# Criterium for algebraicity of an analytic map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ and $Y$ be algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f:X^{an}\to Y^{an}$ be a holomorphic map.

Is the following statement correct?

> > If there is an algebraic variety $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and a dominant morphism $V\to X$ such that the composed holomorphic map $V^{an}\to X^{an}\to Y^{an}$ is algebraic, then the map $X^{an}\to Y^{an}$ is algebraic.

I think one can check algebraicity of $f$ on a dense open of $X$. If that's true, one can assume $V\to X$ is fppf. Can we now somehow use that the functor of points of $X$ is an fppf sheaf?

I looked at SGA1, Expose XII, but I couldn't find the relevant result.

Comment: Consider the induced morphism from $V$ to $X\times Y$ whose projection to each factor is your morphism from above.  What is the closed image of this induced morphism?

Comment: @JasonStarr I get the feeling that it's the (closure of the) graph of $f$. Is that all?

Comment: Why do you write "closure of the" in your comment?  Are you allowing $Y$ to be non-separated?  Anyway, if you denote by $\Gamma$ the image of $V$, what does your hypothesis imply about the analytification of the projection $\Gamma \to X$?  For a morphism of finite type, separated, irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-schemes, if the fiber over every point is a singleton, is the morphism finite?  If the morphism is finite and the induced maps of stalks are isomorphisms after analytification, is the morphism an isomorphism?

Comment: @JasonStarr Ok, I think I understand what you mean. (Sorry for writing "closure of the". My varieties are separated, so graphs are closed.)  The morphism $\Gamma\to X$ is indeed an isomorphism by the hypothesis (i.e., existence of $V$), precisely by what you say. And yes, the morphism is an isomorphism, because the stalks are isomorphic after analytification. Thank you very much! Please make your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it.